# Homomorphism between finite group and permutation group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions

Let $S_{n}$ be the permutation group of $n$ elements. If $F$ is finite group, then a homomorphism $f : F \rightarrow S_{n}$ is called regular if the corresponding action of $F$ on $E$, the set of $n$ elements, is free, i.e. if $f(x).e=e$ for some $x\in F$ and $e\in E$, then $x=1$.

My question is that is it true that if the order of group $F$ divides $n$ then there is a regular homomorphism $f : F \rightarrow S_{n}$ and such a homomorphism is unique up to conjugation by an element of $S_{n}$?

Comment: It would be helpful if you used standard terminology. What you are describing is called a semiregular action. it is regular if it isi semiregular and transitive. But in a  semiregular action, the action on every orbit is equivalent to the left regular action, so the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: I actually want to prove a lemma in Serre's book, Trees. To be exact, it is in the proof of Proposition 11, page 120 of that book. That is why I use this terminology.

Comment: Ah well that is probably a translation from French.

Answer (score 1):

Write $n=pq$ where the order of $F$ is $p$ consider the set o $np$ elements $F^q$ on which $F$ acts b left translations.

Comment: I still do not understand why your statement implies the question I asked.